# Switch user in GitHub CLI

Tags: git, windows-10, github-cli

I am using GitHub CLI and [MinGit for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.31.0.windows.1).

When I logout of GitHub CLI with `gh auth logout` and log back in with different account by calling `gh auth login` git config does not change.

When I type `git config --global --list` the `user.name` and `user.email` entries still point to the old account. So when I commit, it looks like the commit was made by my old account.

I know I could type `git config --global user.name "username"` and change the name but how can I do this correctly with GitHub CLI?

If I cannot do this with GitHub CLI are `user.name` and `user.email` the only two entries I need to change to commit as my new account?

Answer (score 6):

Setting the environmental variable `GH_CONFIG_DIR` allows you to change where gh cli looks for your authorization/credentials.

This means that you can use a tool like DirEnv to set up a different GitHub authorization in each project/directory.

For example:

```
cd project_dir/
echo $GH_CONFIG_DIR # likely returns blank
gh auth status # will show you logged in to account 1

export GH_CONFIG_DIR=.config # set GH_CONFIG_DIR to local .config
gh auth status # will now show you not logged in to any account

gh auth login # you can now log in to account 2
```

Comment: How does this affect the `.gitconfig` where the committer's name and email are stored?

Answer (score 4):

A new command has been added. You can use the following

```
gh auth switch
```

For further information you may check this out
https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_switch

Answer (score -1):

Changing Your Committer Name & Email Globally

ex-:

```
git config --global user.name "John"
git config --global user.email "john@gmail.com"
```

Changing the Author Information Just for the Next Commit

```
git commit --author="John<john@gmail.com>"
```

learn more -: https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/change-author-name-email/