# gh auth login always tries to log into wrong account

Tags: git, github

I used `gh auth login` to log into one account.  That works fine.

I try to use `gh auth login` to log into another account for unrelated work.  It tries to log me into the first account.  I don't want that, I want to log into the second account.  I can't find an option to switch direction.

I have tried:

- logging out of that account in browser
- setting `GH_CONFIG_DIR`.  Directory sets fine.  I can see the new config.yml and hosts being created.  But the browser still takes me to the wrong account.
- installing `gh extension install gabe565/gh-profile`.  Looks awesome!  But still takes me to the account I don't want right now, and didn't ask for.
- just looking around in the UI and the gh CLI for another option to switch accounts.  Can't find one.

I don't want to uninstall everything and install gh over again.  I use the other account.  But now I need this one.

Going bonkers.  Help?

(Using linux)

Comment: What does `gh auth status` tell you?

Comment: Also, I notice that you do not mention `GITHUB_TOKEN` (or --with-token).

Comment: At the moment, "You are not logged into any GitHub hosts. Run gh auth login to authenticate."

GITHUB_TOKEN is not set.

Comment: Well, that is why I said you didn't mention `GITHUB_TOKEN`. It's actually good that it is isn't set! In that case you can use `--with-token` to specify which token you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

I can read your question, but I don't fully understand it, so if you want to login to another GitHub account, you must follow these steps.

First, get (if created) or generate a new github token for this:

You can do this in the following github link:

- https://github.com/settings/tokens

Once the new tokens are generated, you can authenticate in the gh cli in your terminal:

```bash
echo <github-token> | gh auth login --with-token
```

Check which user you are logged in with:

```bash
gh auth status
```

You should see something similar to this:

[image: gh auth status]

Ok, connected to the first account, do the same procedure to connect to the second account.

Use this command to refresh stored credentials:

```bash
gh auth refresh
```

I also found this other question that seems to address something about `GITHUB_CONFIG_DIR`:

- [Switch user in GitHub CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66777769/switch-user-in-github-cli)

I do this to play between github accounts but it's possible there are other methods for this but this helps me when needed.